# SQL - How do I filter for specific data instead of returning all results?

Tags: sql

In this query I'm getting almost everything I need.  The only problem is I want to eliminate the applications that DON'T meet BOTH criteria.

Criteria:

> show app_id's where rel_data for field_id 22222 = '' AND rel_data for field_id 55555 = U.

```
SELECT distinct app_id, alr.loan_id, field_id, rel_data from loan_field_rel lfr
LEFT JOIN app_loan_rel alr ON alr.loan_id=lfr.loan_id
WHERE field_id IN (22222, 55555) AND rel_data IN ('', 'U') 
GROUP BY app_id, rel_data, alr.loan_id, field_id
ORDER BY app_id
```

I should see only lines like this with 2808 results, but I'm getting 13,000 results:

```
app_id          loan_id    field_id     rel_data
25791           791        22222    
25791           791        55555        U
```

I know it's something really simple but any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
... where ( field_id = 22222 and rel_data = '' ) OR ( field_id = 55555 and rel_data = 'U' )
```

Correction:

```
SELECT distinct app_id, alr.loan_id, field_id, rel_data 
from app_loan_rel alr
LEFT JOIN loan_field_rel lfr22222 ON alr.loan_id=lfr.loan_id and field_id = 22222
LEFT JOIN loan_field_rel lfr55555 ON alr.loan_id=lfr.loan_id and field_id = 55555
WHERE lfr22222.rel_data = ''
    AND lfr55555.rel_data = 'U'
GROUP BY app_id, rel_data, alr.loan_id, field_id
ORDER BY app_id
```

Comment: Thanks, This gave me the same 13,000 results.  I don't know sql well enough to filter out the app_id's that don't match both values for the two field_id's in rel_data.

Comment: Oh, I see - that's a bit more complicated because in your query they are in two different rows. In that case I would left join to the table that has field_id twice - once for the id 22222 and again for the id 55555. That will put the results for each application into one row, and then you can filter using AND.

Comment: Update - that's off the cuff but maybe closer?

Comment: Thanks!  I had to manipulate the aliases a bit but I was able to pull only those records!!

Answer (score 0):

```
  where  (  field_id=2222 and rel_data='') or (field_id=5555 and rel_data=U)
```

Comment: Please do not simply dump code, always add an explanation to show how what you've written is relevant to the question